# Ionic React onIonChange being triggered on page load

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a page with some IonInputs, which are having its initial values set with data from a fetch.
My problem is that the onIonChange event is triggering as soon as i load the page.
The change is calling a function that is setting some variables that shouldn't be set unless a user has manually inputted a value.
I was sure for initial page render , the Ion Change event shouldn't be triggered but i cannot find any info in the docs or on general search.
Can any one tell me how to stop the onIonchange event happening when pragmatically setting the value, or even to wait for values to be set before render? Please see my code snips below Ive taken out unneeded code. I'm using react 18 and ionic 6

MyPage.tsx

```
    const [person, setPerson] = useState<People>({}as People);
    const [addressType, setAddressType] = useState(""); 
    const [employer, setEmployer] = useState<People>({} as People); 

    useIonViewWillEnter(async()=>{
            let person = {} as People;
            if(urlParams.get('UUID') != undefined && urlParams.get('UUID') != null ){ 
                person = await getPersonByUUID("" + urlParams.get('UUID')) 
                localStorage.setItem("ABPerson", JSON.stringify(person))
            } 
            else { 
                person =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ABPerson") ?? "null") ?? {} as People;
            }
            let employer = await getPersonByUUID(person?.employeeOf?.toString())
            
            setPerson(person);
            setEmployer(employer)
            setAddressType(person?.typeString?.toString());
    });

    return(
        <IonPage className="AddressBook">
            <IonInput 
                id="nameInput" 
                type="text" 
                className="textInput"                                                 
                value={person.name} 
                onIonChange={(e)=>HandleDetailsUpdate("name", e.detail.value)}>
            </IonInput>
        </IonPage>
)
```

Comment: Update.  I created a new page, and set a static value to the IonInput on useIonViewWillEnter in effort to remove the fetches. The OnIonChange event is still triggered. This behavior doesn't happen when using standard input tags, just when using IonInput. I guess this is a workaround for now, but id prefer to use the Ionic wrapped tags.

Comment: Update 2: As of Ionic 7 this has now been fixed. onIonChange no longer triggers when being set on page load

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution works for you:

[onIonChange is triggering more than one input on Ionic 5 React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077542/onionchange-is-triggering-more-than-one-input-on-ionic-5-react)

In the meantime, I would try to replace:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState<People>({}as People);
...
value={person.name}
```

By:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState<People>();
...
value={person?.name}
```

This will initiate the state variable person to undefined and you won't have cast an empty object to People.